# Getting parse error message in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, syntax-error

Getting error message:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'`

I edited my functions.php and I cannot get back in to make it work again. don't know how to reset it or even try to get into wordpress appearance > editor > functions.php

Comment: restore file from backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will have happened because you have a mistake in the code that you have entered. To fix this you will need to undo the changes you have made to the `functions.php` file. You will have to do this with either ftp access or control panel.

The `functions.php` file can be found in the following location: `[INSTALLATIONFOLDER/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/functions.php`

Once you have found that file, edit it and undo the changes you have made.

Comment: But that wouldn't matter for the control panel of your webhost?

Comment: i'm inside my ftp for the site, but can't locate the right functions.php file to replace it with the default theme......i've located the backup but i don't know how i'd even load that in if I can't access the wordpress admin

Comment: In the default theme, there should only be one `functions.php` file

Comment: there is, under wp-includes...but it doesn't match the one in the theme i'm using

Comment: Go into the `wp-content/themes/[themename]` folder and find it there.

Comment: i found it, and uploaded the file from my local location.....but no changes.....odd

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)

Comment: Np, if the answer helped you solve your problem, feel free to mark it as correct so others who have a problem like yours will know how you solved it.